# Mount.cifs vs. SMBClient

Tags: command-line

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 to connect to a Windows 2008 Server:

If I use

```
mount.cifs //server/share /mnt/mountpoint -o username=domain/credentials
```

I successfully connect, but if I try to `cp` a file, I get `access is denied`.

If I use

```
smbclient //server/share -o domain/credentials
```

I can successfully 'put' the file on the server.

Why does `mount.cifs` fail but `SMBClient` work?

Comment: "Why" does it work answer: because smbclient is a client application similar to ftp (as you've mentioned using 'put' command).  If the "why" part is based on you did a 'put' to the path '/mnt/mountpoint/' directory and it works on smbclient and not mount.cifs, then you need to provide more information (such as whether you're su or normal user, etc).

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you add write permissions for your user on /mnt/mountpoint. One way would be `chown username /mnt/mountpoint`

Answer (score 1):

In case that normally the mount on console is done for more than on user, you should prefer to set the write permissions and not the ownership of the mount point.

`chmod 775 /path/to/mountpoint`

Have a look that the user has to be also in group, otherwise (net preferred) you have to set `777` as global rights.

If you just want to use mounts on a per user base, you can use FUSE filesystem and mount via gvfs (if using gnome) via your desktop. Look for `fusemount`, so mounting is also possible on a per user basis.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permissions problem, be sure your samba user can write to the directory. Did you mount using sudo?

Try to cp with sudo.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks Phil.  Using sudo to 'cp' the file worked.  Apparently since I used sudo to mount the share, I need sudo to use the share as well.